# Recode multiple values in multiple columns with new values in R

Tags: r, replace, recode

I have data frame with 18 columns. Columns 2 to 13 include numeric values such as 0, 1, 2, 4 ... I want to recode them based on range into three categories:

```
if columns 2:13 are 0 -> 0
if columns 2:13 between 1 & 5 -> 1
else columns 2:13 >- 2.
```

My attempt works, but not efficient:

```
df[,2:13][df[,2:13] == 1 | df[,2:13] == 2 | df[,2:13] == 3 | df[,2:13] == 4 | df[,2:13] == 5] <- 1
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `findInterval`:

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(2:13, ~ findInterval(., c(0, 1, 5), rightmost.closed = TRUE) - 1L)
  )
```

If this gets any more complex (such as non-consecutive recoded values), we might switch to `case_when`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(2:13, ~ case_when(
      . == 0           ~ 0L,
      between(., 1, 5) ~ 1L,
      TRUE             ~ 2L
    ))
  )
```

## base R

```r
df[,2:13] <- lapply(df[,2:13], function(z) findInterval(z, c(0, 1, 5), rightmost.closed = TRUE) - 1L)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I was not aware of findInterval function.

Comment: It's very similar to `cut`, useful for returning strings/labels (including number-range looking things)